# HP Battery not charging on windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I have run into the issue of windows 10 not charging my battery. I can understand it if it wouldn't charge when higer than x % however this is not the case, with my battery currently being at 0%

Before asking my question I have tried to fix it myself by using the following advice;

```
1) Disconnect AC
2) Shutdown
3) Remove battery
4) Connect AC
5) Startup
6) Under the Batteries category (in Device Manager), right-click the Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery listing, and select Uninstall. Do this for each instance (I had 2 batteries installed, so 2 instances. Most users will only have 1).
7) Shutdown
8) Disconnect AC
9) Insert battery
10) Connect AC
11) Startup
```

I've contacted support also, one saying that I should contact microsoft whilst the other saying I should contact HP. Basically not helping me

With that not working and wanting to rule out the hardware I bought a new battery and used several different AC adapters. None of them fixing this issue, also I have tried using system restore to put it back to a later date. This did not seem to fix anything either, should I do a clean install of windows or are there any other options for me to try out?

Comment: Windows doesn't decide when or if your battery charges. The hardware does. This behavior is hardware related. Have you tried a BIOS update? If you've tried known good batteries and power adapters, then it's your motherboard (possibly powerjack damage). Hopefully your laptop is under warranty.

Comment: Well my laptop is 3 years old about now, so I doubt there is any warranty. I've come across the issue a lot and that seemed to be a battery issue. I have not tried a BIOS update, would that be a better option to try?